# How to set the parent pom version on a project

Tags: maven, version, parent, pom.xml

I'm using the versions plugin to... set versions.

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=XXXX
```

That work's great on aggregate project with declared modules

Now my question is how, in other maven project can I change the parent pom version ? I've placed high hopes in the versions:update-parent but I would like just to set the parent with the version i'm specifying regardless whether that version is deployed or not. Besides I can't get it to work. It never modifies the actual pom. Is there a way to do just that using a mvn plug-in ? Right now it's a manual pom.xml edit.

Thanks

Aa.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use release plugin for that. It changes version of the parent and all the submodules:

`mvn release:update-versions -DautoVersionSubmodules=true`

Details are here:
http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/update-versions.html

Comment: Thanks but my question is how to edit the pom of another project ( not sub modules of a project).